# Quarkus service using Kafka Streams with GlobalKTable tries to connect to bootstrap servers during test

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, quarkus

I am using Kafka Streams (Version 3.4.0) within a Quarkus microservice (version 2.14.3).
My streams topology uses GlobalKTable with a statestore to allow all instances of the microservice full access to the statestore. I have written a unit test using the TopologyTestDriver and the test does not work when using GlobalKTable because it tries to connect to the kafka broker defined in the quarkus test-profile.

So my topology with GlobalKTable is very simple:

```
builder.globalTable(
           "input-Topic",
           Materialized.<Long, CustomAvro, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(
                           KafkaStreamsProperties.STATE_STORE)
                   .withKeySerde(Serdes.Long())
                   .withValueSerde(CustomAvroSerde)
   );
```

Here is how my test looks like:

```
@BeforeEach
public void setup() {

    topologyTestDriver = new TopologyTestDriver(myTopology, "app-id-1");

    inputTopic = topologyTestDriver.createInputTopic(
            "input-topic",
            new StringSerializer(),
            new CustomAvroSerializer());

}

@Test
public void test() {
    inputTopic.pipeInput("some-uuid", createValue());
    KeyValueStore<Long, CustomAvro> store = topologyTestDriver.getKeyValueStore(
            KafkaStreamsProperties.STATE_STORE);
    CustomAvro value = store.get(10L);
    assertEquals(10L, somePartOfMyValue);
}
```

And the errors I get when starting the test:
*Restoring state for global store state-store*, *Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.* & *Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected*

I switched from the GlobalKTable to a normal KTable using the same quarkus profile configuration and the test works fine.

I do not get why it does not work with GlobalKTable. The only difference I see in the log output is that with GlobalKTable the app is trying to restore the state store which does not happen with KTable.

Comment: I think it's more likely you will get an answer to this if you include a minimal example which shows what doesn't work with `TopologyTestDriver`

Comment: I've added the relevant code snippets